# Cell takes separate color from overlay UIVIew

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ipad, uikit

This bug is reproducing only on iPad, on iPhone it is working correctly.
I have grouped UITableView and in last cell in first section have this code for remove separator:

```
self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,CGFLOAT_MAX);
```

and it's look well.

[image]

but if i add and them remove another UIView to viewController view above tableView:

```
UIView *coloredView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
coloredView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview: coloredView];
[coloredView performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
```

my last cell will be like that:

[image]

How i can fix it or remove separator from last cell with another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to customize seperator behavior on a per-cell basis. It's not really supported, and as you can see the inset hack you're using has limitations.

I would recommend using `tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` to remove all separators. Then add a small colored 1pt UIView to each cell, to *simulate* an actual separator - on all cells except the last cell.

You can use different cell subclasses, or just insert the view in your storyboard using different cell identifiers; use auto layout to ensure it sticks to the bottom of the cell and doesn't exceed 1pt height.

It's really the best you can do, plus it gives you the benefit of being able to customize separator color.

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you remove the separator by choosing None for separator?

[image]